# Symfony2 - Form with a checkbox column

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I'm trying to build an HTML table with some data of an entity, and then, add a column with a checkbox for each row, in order to validate if the precious data is valid or not. After user checks or not each checkbox, I have to update the database table with this info.

As when I build the form I don't know exactly how many checkboxes I have, I pass to twing template an array of entities, and then I buid a new `input type"checkbox"` at last column for each row.

But when I submit my form (POST method), I'm not able to get this info. `$request` object doesn't have any of the checkboxes nor form reference. `$request->request->all()` is getting a null value. How can I get fields of a manual form build in a twig template?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use Symfony Forms component?

Comment: No, because I don't know the number of rows in the table... so I don't know the number of checkboxes. I generate checkboxes in twig template as input type="checkbox"

Comment: Now It's working. Thanks a lot ($request->request->all() is getting values now) It's a mistery...

Answer (score 0):

Now It's working. Thanks a lot ($request->request->all() is getting values now). It's a mistery...